# Do we allow questions about Lout?

Tags: discussion, scope

Do we allow questions regarding the Typesetting language [Lout](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/lout-an-alternative-to-latex/) on this site?

Comment: Related discussion of troff http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507/is-troff-groff-a-friend-of-tex

Answer (score 10):

No, I don't think so. This site is about TeX, LaTeX and related software, not other software which tries to do the same or similar things.

However a question about how to convert Lout to LaTeX should be acceptable, but is already borderline.